# System Dialog Input with Button

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to create a button that uses `SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]` to browse for a file and assigns the file name to a variable.

For example:

```
 {Button["Select the file", fname = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]], Dynamic[fname]}
```

This works most of the time; however, when the file that I browse to is several nested folders away from the default directory, it does not update the value of fname.

Is there some way around this?  Or is there a better function to use?  I eventually would like to use this button within `Manipulate`.

Comment: Try adding the option `Method->"Queued"` to your `Button`.

Comment: related Q/As: [Why do buttons with ChoiceDialog freeze the front end?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5356/125) and [Dialog inside Dynamic Module](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15602/125)

Answer (score 3):

The `Method -> "Queued"` option is important.

I also suggest to use current or data file directory as a starting point.

Also do not forget to check file if it is "$Canceled" (in the event of cancellation).

Here is an example just copied from one of my programs:

```
Button["Load", file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {NotebookDirectory[] <> "data\\",
      {"Data files" -> {"*.txt"}}}];
      If[ file != "$Canceled", data = Get[file]; ], Method -> "Queued"]
```